# Connecting to C++ server from PHP too many times causes access violation exception

Tags: php, c++, sockets, exception, memory

So I've got a C++ server and it has some data in it that I would like to access from PHP.
However I need to be able to handle the fact that many people may connect to it at once, and flood the server with tons of packets.

I simply have a PHP script that opens a socket, sends "hello" to it, and closes the socket.
If I refresh the page on the browser over and over, it floods the server. However, after sending around 70->100 packets (connecting to socket, sending the data, closing the socket  over 70 times), I get an access violation exception:

> Unhandled exception at 0x010BC96D in Server.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFEEEFEEE.

[image: Variable dump]

Here's my tcp connection setup:

```
double webListen = tcplisten(cst::WEB_PORT, 100, 1);

std::list<double> webUsers;

if (webListen <= 0) {
    cout << "Failed to listen on port " << cst::WEB_PORT <<endl;
}
cout << endl << "Server listening on port " << cst::WEB_PORT << endl;
while(1){
    //Sleep(5);
    double WebUser = tcpaccept(webListen, 0);
    if(WebUser > -1){
        cout<< "NEW WEB SOCKET: " << WebUser <<  endl;
        webUsers.push_back(WebUser);
    }

    std::list<double>::iterator it = webUsers.begin();
    while (it != webUsers.end())
    {

        cout << "SOCK: " << *it << endl;
        double Size = receivemessage(*it, 1024, 4);
        if(Size == -1){

        }
        else if(Size == 0){
            cout << "WEB SOCKET DISCONNECTED: " << *it << endl;
            it = webUsers.erase(it);
        }
        else if(Size > 0){
            cout << "SIZE: " << Size << endl;
            //Not reading data until exception is fixed
        }

    }

}
```

(I put 4 in the arguments for receivemessage() because its
And here's my receivemessage() function:

```
int CSocket::receivemessage(int len, CBuffer*destination)
{
    if(sockid<0)return -1;
    int size = -1;
    //std::vector<char> buff;
    std::vector<char> *buff;
    if(udp)
    {
        size = 8195;
        //buff = new char[size];
        buff = new std::vector<char>(size,'0');
        size = recvfrom(sockid, &(*buff)[0], size, 0, (SOCKADDR *)&SenderAddr, &SenderAddrSize);
    } else
    {
        if(format == 0 && !len)
        {
            unsigned short length;
            if(recv(sockid, (char*)&length, 2, 0) == SOCKET_ERROR)return -1;
            buff = new std::vector<char>(length,'0');
            //buff = new char[length];
            size = recv(sockid, &(*buff)[0], length, 0);
        } else if(format == 1 && !len)
        {
            size = 65536;
            buff = new std::vector<char>(size,'0');
            //buff = new char[size];
            size = receivetext(&(*buff)[0], size);
        } else if(format == 2 || len > 0)
        {
            buff = new std::vector<char>(len,'0');
            //buff = new char[len];
            size = recv(sockid, &(*buff)[0], len, 0);
        }
    }
    if(size > 0)
    {
        destination->clear();
        destination->addBuffer(&(*buff)[0], size);
    }
    delete buff;
    //if(buff != NULL)delete[] buff;
    return size;
}
```

And also my PHP script:

```
   <?php
    require_once("../server_info.php"); //contains get_host() and get_port_web()
    $waitTimeoutInSeconds = 1; 
    $errCode = 0;
    $errStr = 0;

    if(!($sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)))
    {
        $errorcode = socket_last_error();
        $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

        die("Couldn't create socket: [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
    }

    echo "Socket created \n";

    //Connect socket to remote server

    if(!socket_connect($sock , get_host() , get_port_web()))
    {
        $errorcode = socket_last_error();
        $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

        die("Could not connect: [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
    }

    echo "Connection established \n";

    $message = "hello";

    //Send the message to the server
    if( ! socket_send ( $sock , $message , strlen($message) , 0))
    {
        $errorcode = socket_last_error();
        $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

        die("Could not send data: [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
    }

    echo "Message sent successfully \n";

    socket_close($sock);

?>
```

I'm not sure why after around 70-100 sockets cause it to exception. Do I have a memory leak somewhere? (possibly in the receivemessage() function?).

Sometimes its even at more than 34 socket connections that it throws an exception.
Not sure what to do at this point.

Comment: Have you tried checking so that the buffer is really allocated before deleting it: `std::vector<char>* buff = 0; if(buff) { delete buff; }`. Shouldn't you also break the loop if `tcpaccept()` returns -1?

Comment: 1. instead of vector you can use `std::array` 2. don't use dynamic allocation, if you insist you must check if you have succeeded to allocate before you continue.

Comment: Okay I set buff to 0 when initializing it now and I checked if(buff) then delete it. Also if tcpaccept() is -1 then no one basically tried to connect, no point in breaking. 

Also I don't believe my visual studio 2012 support C++11 members such as std::array so I need to use std::vector.

What would you change in the receivemessage() in order to check if I succeeded to allocate memory?

Also I'm still getting the exception, none of the above in Cyclone's comment fixed it.

Here's my latest receivemessage() function:
[link](http://pastebin.com/qQfrpkK6)

Comment: Does your code compile without warnings? I guess not, because you are storing the result of tcpaccept() in a double. That said, you are using new like a Java programmer, which is surely wrong in C++.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't test a pointer for NULL before deleting it, the language guarantees that delete(NULL) will do nothing.
Also, take a look at your code and see if you really need that to be a pointer. Wouldn't it be easier if you made it a simple vector?

Coming back to your crash, there's a big chance the reason for it is not in the piece of code you posted.

> Access violation reading location 0xFEEEFEEE.

If you look in the Locals window you'll notice that 'this' points to 0xFEEEFEEE, which is a magic number in Windows: in debug builds it's the value assigned to freed heap space.
So it looks like at some point receivemessage() gets called on a deleted CSocket object. This is the area where I would start looking for the cause.

Comment: Well I decided to then in the code where I call receivemessage(), to check if the listening socket (webListen) is -1 or if the new socket we accepted (WebUser) is -1, and if so to continue in the loop, but I still seem to be getting the exception..

I don't delete the socket anywhere in my code at all..
Here's my new code where I call receivemessage(): http://pastebin.com/N97a5rKn

Comment: As I said, there's a big chance the crash isn't caused by this particular piece of code. This piece is inside a CSocket class apparently, Is there a chance you could show us the rest of the program or a minimal test case? In particular the pieces that create and destroy CSocket objects.

Comment: I believe I found out the problem. It has nothing to do with CSocket objects getting deleted because there's still data intact. The receivemessage() function is being called in multiple threads in their own respective while loops. The problem appears to arrise if both of those threads try to call receivemessage() at the same time.

What can I do to prevent this from happening? I tried locking a mutex around it both receivemessage() calls but that didn't work.

Comment: If that were the cause and you properly synchronized the calls with a mutex it should have worked, right? So maybe that's not the root cause... But the multithreading aspect is something you should have mentioned from the start. Again, based solely on the first two screenshot which show the variable states and the location of the crash, I'm sticking to the idea that it calls that method on a deleted object. Maybe it gets deleted on a thread and then gets accessed on another, but you have to show us more code if you want more help.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that either tcpaccept() or receivemessage() were having some sort of deadlock situation because they were run in multiple threads and needed to be accessed at the same time at some point.

My solution was to simply lock a mutual exclusion around both of them, or just keep them all in the same thread.